# Developing Visual Studio Extensions getting the current forecolor

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In my WPF user control, if user has a dark theme all my texts which are by default black will be hard to read. What's the correct way of using **VS** current colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do in two ways by writing your own Visual Studio style brushes and merge with controls.

In another way, you can pick resources of VS theme from Windows Registry. Long time before I used a Utility class to pick the current theme from windows Registry.

```
public enum VsTheme
{
    Unknown = 0, 
    Light, 
    Dark, 
    Blue
}

public class ThemeUtil
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<string, VsTheme> Themes = new Dictionary<string, VsTheme>()
    {
        { "de3dbbcd-f642-433c-8353-8f1df4370aba", VsTheme.Light }, 
        { "1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749", VsTheme.Dark }, 
        { "a4d6a176-b948-4b29-8c66-53c97a1ed7d0", VsTheme.Blue }
    };

    public static VsTheme GetCurrentTheme()
    {
        string themeId = GetThemeId();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(themeId) == false)
        {
            VsTheme theme;
            if (Themes.TryGetValue(themeId, out theme))
            {
                return theme;
            }
        }

        return VsTheme.Unknown;
    }

    public static string GetThemeId()
    {
        const string CategoryName = "General";
        const string ThemePropertyName = "CurrentTheme";
        string keyName = string.Format(@"Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\{0}", CategoryName);

        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keyName))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                return (string)key.GetValue(ThemePropertyName, string.Empty);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I've found another way to do it. I can use visual studio theme colors resources from xaml directly.For these you need to have **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0.(for VS2013)** Its a resdistributable component for VisualStudio versions. once you added through your project you can straight way access all brushes as key in your XAML itself. For Example

```
Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsfx:VsBrushes.EnvironmentBackgroundGradientKey}}"
```

NameSpace have to add as

```
xmlns:vsfx="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0"
```

You can refer all Brushes from the following MSDN Link

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsbrushes(v=vs.120).aspx](http://MSDN)

If you want to detect the theme change event itself, you can make use of the **VSColorTheme.ThemeChanged** Event

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.platformui.vscolortheme.themechanged.aspx](http://ColorTheme)

Comment: ShineKing, this is returning the CurrentTheme. Could you show me how to use it in the Xaml for example how to set the color of a label based on that.

Comment: Mohsen, I have found another way to refer brushes of VS straightway to xaml. Sure its works for you. Please see my edited code

Comment: Hi ShineKing, I think I am still missing something. It's still not working. Would you mind share your solution somewhere.